# Disney Musicians Ordering

Tags: knowledge, find-the-order

At our wedding we named our tables after Disney characters playing musical instruments, because we are musicians who love Disney! We have now decided to hang the drawings up the stairs in our new house but we can't agree on an order. Here is my suggestion, which my husband doesn't understand:

```
Top of Stairs
  Woody and Jessie, Clarinets
  Olaf, Cymbals
  Stitch, Maracas
  Mushu, Gong
  Pocahontas, Singing
  Genie, Saxophone
  Aladdin, Banjo
  Ariel, Harp (with Sebastian conducting)
  Cinderella, Flute
  Snow White, Cello
Bottom of Stairs
```

Technically, Woody and Jessie shouldn't be where they are, but they were our top table so they take pride of place at the top of the stairs.

Can you help my husband figure out what my ordering is?

**Bonus Question**: where should Woody and Jessie go?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you ascend the stairs in your house, your pictures (with the exception of Woody and Jessie) are:

> Arranged chronologically, with the characters appearing in the order in which their Disney films were released.  Characters from the same film are further arranged in the order in which they first sing/perform in a song in the Disney canon.  The instruments with which they are depicted are prominent instruments from songs in their film.

As follows:

> Snow White, Cello - *Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs (1937)*
>  Cinderella, Flute - *Cinderella (1950)*
>  Ariel, Harp - *The Little Mermaid (1989)*
>  Aladdin, Banjo - *Aladdin (1992)* - Song: *One Jump Ahead*
>  Genie, Saxophone - *Aladdin (1992)* - Song: *Friend Like Me*
>  Pocahontas, Singing - *Pocahontas (1995)*
>  Mushu, Gong - *Mulan (1998)*
>  Stitch, Maracas - *Lilo and Stitch (2002)*
>  Olaf, Cymbals - *Frozen (2013)*

As for Woody and Jessie:

> The first film in which they both appeared was *Toy Story 2* in 1999.  In this film Jessie performs ‘*When Somebody Loved Me*’ during a conversation with Woody about her previous owner, Emily.  It would therefore make sense for their picture to appear between Mushu and Stitch.
>
>  However, as so often in the Disney canon, love triumphs over everything, so perhaps it is most appropriate that they remain on display in their current location, right at the top!

Comment: Spot on! The instruments were there as a bit of a red herring but I like how you’ve found a way to tie them in too :D

Comment: @lioness99a Thanks. Please tell me it's a true story - I love to imagine it is!

Comment: Yes it is! We haven’t yet hung the pictures but we’re fairly sure this is the order we’re having. The only fabrication in the story was that my husband did understand the order :)